# Output currently executed code from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, exception

In case of an exception you can find out the line where the exception occurred with :

```
int line = (new StackTrace(ex, true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
```

Analogous, I want to output the currently executed code outside of a thread without throwing an exception.
Is this possible?

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);           
myThread.Start();            
myThread.GetLineOfCurrentlyExecutedCode(); // This I want
```

Comment: A `Thread` should be considered as autonomous worker. In other words once it receives all the necessary information for its initialization it works alone without knowing about its caller.  If you need to do any kind of communication between the caller and the callee you should introduce some shared resource.

Comment: Can you use `Task` instead of `Thread`?